# How to 301 redirect to default language

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

I have a problem with site redirection.
So, when I type in browser mysite.com
I get a 301 moved permanent to mysite.com/en

How to write a 301 rule to redirect to my default language.

I want to get status  200 when tge user navigate to my site.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /en [L]
```

Also you need to find the 301 rule/code and comment it out.

Comment: I still get the 301 message. BUt I want to get the 200 message.

Comment: Did you comment out your 301 generating rule/code? Once commented out test in a new browser.

Comment: Well your code runs after the rewrite rules. So if you cannot control/modify your code then you can't reverse a 301 redirection using a rewrite rule.